# How to give a Button a special identifier

Tags: c#, winforms, button, identifier

I am writing an app that generates and saves color schemes.  I need to be able to select a color schemes base color and delete that color scheme.  Each color scheme is represented by a series of buttons (the base color is a button and the other shades are buttons).  When I click on the button, that represents the base color of a color scheme, I need to be able to get what color scheme that button belongs to.

Basically, I need to attach a special identifier (a string) to a button when it is created so I can identify it later.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?  I am using WinForms (unfortunately).

Comment: I am currently toying with the idea of extending the Button class, but would like to explore other routes first.

Comment: You could use `Tag` property of a `Button` to set some identifier there.

Comment: Great!  Thanks a lot.  I looked at that then wrote it off because it takes a object.  Can't believe I did that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) on the Button class (derived from Control) that accepts an arbitrary object.  You can put anything in there you want.